# How can I use function as a recipe for any number from array

Tags: c++, function

In `void in()`, line `if (hoanhao(a[i]))`, I get an error:

> 'hoanhao' cannot be use as a func.

I want to use `hoanhao()` as a recipe so I can get a result from an array.

```cpp
bool hoanhao(int a[], int n){//to get perfect number
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (n%i==0){
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    if (sum==n){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

void in(int a[], int n, bool hoanhao){
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (hoanhao(a[i])){
            cout<<i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `hoanhao` takes two arguments but you're only providing it one.

Comment: And the input parameter `bool hoanhao` shadows your function.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in the posted attempt.

For staters, the first function, the one that should be called for each element of the array, should receive only *one* parameter, the number at test.

It also shouldn't try to evaluate `n % 0`, which results in undefined behavior.

The following is a possible fixed implementation.

```
bool is_perfect_number(int n)
{
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if ( n % i == 0 ) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return  sum == n;
}
```

The second function has other issues.

```
void in(int a[], int n, bool hoanhao){
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is a bool variable, not a function
//                                   returning a bool. 
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (hoanhao(a[i])){
        //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   You cannot invoke a bool        
            cout<<i;
            //    ^   This should be a[i], if you want to show the actual
            //        perfect number and not its index in the array.
        }
    }
}
```

The easiest way to accomplish what seems to be the OP's task is to pass a function parameter.

```
void test(int a[], size_t n, bool (fun)(int))
{//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if ( fun(a[i]) ) {
            std::cout << a[i] << '\n';
        }
    }
}

// At the call site:
// ...
int a[10] = {2, 4, 6, 10, 25, 28, 42, 300, 496, 497};
test(a, 10, is_perfect_number);
// Outputs: 6 28 496
```